# Button refreshes page, and UseEffect not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two buttons in my react.js project, when i click on the css should switch. To do this i have a `onClick` call to a function `flip` which changes the value of a state `pathoButton` from true to false (or vice versa). Then i have a useEffect that should only be run when `pathoButton` is changed and this alters the html. For some reason every time i click a button the whole page refreshes and im not sure what courses this. here is a snippet of some of the code.

where pathoButton is originally set

```
    const [userSettings, setuserSettings] = useState(
        {
            pathoButton: true,
        } 
    );
```

The two buttons which are `pathologyButton` and `treatmentButton` when the `treatmentButton` is clicked `flip` is called

```
return (
      <div className="input-group top-gap">
          <form className="form-length">
              <div className="input-group">
                <button className="pathologyButton">  <dt>Pathology</dt> </button>
                <button className="treatmentButton" onClick={()=>flip()}>  <dt>Treatment</dt> </button> 
              </div>
            <div className="svg-form">
                {displayAnimal()}
                  
            </div>
              
          </form>
          <form className='form-length'>
              <input type="Animal" class="animal-input" placeholder="Search by owner name or animal..." /> 
          </form>

      </div>
    );
```

flip and my use effect, i have tried `window.location.reload(false);` but it does not work

```
    function flip(e){
        window.location.reload(false);
        const pathoB = ! userSettings.pathoButton        
        setuserSettings((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, pathoButton: pathoB };
          });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(userSettings.pathoButton, '<---log\n\n\n')
        if (userSettings.pathoButton) {
            return (<div> 
                <button className="pathologyButton" onClick={()=>flip()}>  <dt>Pathology</dt> </button>
                <button className="treatmentButton" onClick={()=>flip()}>  <dt>Treatment</dt> </button> 
            </div>)
        } else {
            return (<div>
                <button className="treatmentButton" onClick={()=>flip()}>  <dt>Pathology</dt> </button>
                <button className="pathologyButton" onClick={()=>flip()}>  <dt>Treatment</dt> </button> 
            </div>
            )
        }
    }, [userSettings.pathoButton])
```

Sorry if this is a repost of a question! i dont think it is but could be as im unsure what causes the page to refresh and any help or advice would be awesome!

Comment: It's because you have a `<form>` tag around your buttons. When you have that scenario you would have to specify the `type` attribute on button for it will default to `submit` when not specified. This results in you "submitting" your form whenever you click the button and thus reloading the page.

Comment: Ive done a few things to change the code, one was change the type of the button to, `type="button"` but im still getting a refresh

Comment: Did you remove the `window.location.reload(false);` line?

Comment: No, but have now and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try that.

```
const [userSettings, setuserSettings] = useState({pathoButton: true});

function flip(e){
  const pathoB = !userSettings.pathoButton    
  setuserSettings((prevState) => { ...prevState, pathoButton: pathoB });
}

function buttons() {
  if (userSettings.pathoButton) {
    return (
      <div> 
        <button className="pathologyButton" onClick={()=>flip()}> <dt>Pathology</dt> </button>
        <button className="treatmentButton" onClick={()=>flip()}> <dt>Treatment</dt> </button> 
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="treatmentButton" onClick={()=>flip()}> <dt>Pathology</dt> </button>
        <button className="pathologyButton" onClick={()=>flip()}> <dt>Treatment</dt> </button> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

return (
  <div className="input-group top-gap">
    <form className="form-length">
      {buttons()}
      <div className="svg-form">
        {displayAnimal()}
      </div>
    </form>
    <form className='form-length'>
      <input type="Animal" class="animal-input" placeholder="Search by owner name or animal..." /> 
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

So have the buttons returned by a function, since their order depend on a state.

Forget about the `useEffect` for that, since the click event already sets the state, which re-renders the component already.

Use a button `type="button"` to prevent the form submission... And never again use a `window.reload` unless you know that all other component states, Redux store and all you can think of will also reset and that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The default `type` attribute of a `button` is `submit` which means that when you use

```
<form>
  <button>test</button>
</form>
```

this button submits the form. Again, by default, without doing anything else, a form is submitted as `GET` so in your case, this gives you a reload.

If you do NOT want the buttons to submit the form, you have to specify `type="button"` on them:

```
<form>
  <button type="button">this does not submit the form</button>
</form>
```